# Recursive ftp sync using perl Net::FTP is painfully slow

Tags: perl, ftp

I've written something rather simple to sync my files via ftp in perl

```
sub ftp_update {
    print "Checkin\' $_[0] \n";
    $ftp->cwd($_[0]);
    chdir $_[0];
    my @ls = $ftp->ls;

    foreach (@ls) {         
        ftp_update($_) if $ftp->isdir($_);

        next unless (! -e $_);

        if ($ftp->isfile($_)) {
            print "Gettin\' $_\n";
            $ftp->get($_);
        }               
    }
    $ftp->cdup;
    chdir "..";
}
```

It works all right but it is painfully slow compared to FileZilla. Even when everything is up to date, i.e. no actual file transfer occurs it is still much, much slower than FileZilla.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: FileZilla probably uses a lot of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `mirror()` function from `LWP::Simple` work for the `"ftp:"` schema? The example shows both `"http:"` and `"gopher:"`, so perhaps it will work for FTP as well.

But I’m curious — if you already have another program that does what you need, just what is it that you’re looking for?